# How to scrape a specific class with asp.net (htmlpackagility)

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to scrape the flight information from a website but my code gets me all the html. The listevol that I used is always empty. I changed the div and the id many times but still not working. I have added some comments in the code hope its clear. Kindly help!

My C# code:

```
public class Program
{
    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetHtmlAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async void GetHtmlAsync()
    {
        var url = "https://www.kayak.com/flights/FEZ-PAR/2019-08-25?sort=bestflight_a";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument(); \\here i get all the html with no problem

        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
        var listevol = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id", "")
            .Equals("item")).ToList(); \\ here my listevol is alwasys empty
}
```

Comment: does this: var listevol = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id", "")
mean find the div that has a id of nothing?

Comment: no i used.equals it means find the div that has id="item"

Comment: there are no divs on that page that have a id="item"